# Is there a way to get the last message produced in Kafka topic using camel?

Tags: spring, apache-kafka, apache-camel

I have a kafka topic with one partition. When my server restarts, I want to consume the last produced message from the topic.

Comment: Hi, you can resume consuming from the earliest message produced in the topic but you can't guarantee that it's the really last one.
Yes Kafka seems supported from Camel 2.13 : https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/kafka-component.html

Answer (score 0):

When your Kafka consumer connects **for the first time** to the topic, you can choose by configuration if you want to

- consume the whole topic from the beginning
- consume only new messages that arrive after your consumer connected

However, from this moment, the **broker saves the latest [topic offset](https://dattell.com/data-architecture-blog/understanding-kafka-consumer-offset/) of your consumer** and **your consumer always continues consuming from this offset on**.

To always just consume the latest message, you would have to change the topic offset of your consumer before starting it.